# How to share twitter even when pop-up is blocked using javascript in website

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using twitter share button, which opens as a popup twitter window, but it fails to open when pop-up is blocked.

Is there any java-script which forces to use twitter even if popup is blocked?

Any help will be appreciated !!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Usually, popups are blocked when they get opened asynchronously and NOT by a user action (such as button click).

To walk around the popup blocker, i suggest using the following:

html:

```
<input type="button" id="btn_tw" value="Share on Twitter" />
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('btn_tw').addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url='+ URL +'&text='+ TEXT, 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
});
```

(`URL` is the url you want to share, `TEXT` is the post caption)

in this way, you use the feature manually, even without the twitter javascript sdk included.

hope that helps, and bypasses the popup blocker.